# FullSimplify of Dirac Delta Function failed

Tags: simplifying-expressions, syntax, calculus-and-analysis

I have `t1` and `t2` whose difference should be `0`. But `FullSimplify` didn't output that, which output `-DiracDelta[f - f0] + DiracDelta[-f + f0]` instead. How can I force it to output `0`?

```
t1 = DiracDelta[-f + f0];
t2 = DiracDelta[f - f0];
t1 - t2 // FullSimplify
```

Similar case for `t3` and `t4`:

```
t3 = -(1/2) I A E^(I \[Theta]) DiracDelta[-f + f0] + 1/2 A DiracDelta[f + f0] (I Cos[\[Theta]] + Sin[\[Theta]]);
t4 = 1/2 I A (-E^(I \[Theta]) DiracDelta[f - f0] + E^(-I \[Theta]) DiracDelta[f + f0]);
t3 - t4 // FullSimplify
```

Many thanks!

Comment: _Mathematica_ can at least prove that they are 0 by integration: `Integrate[t1-t2,f]` and `Integrate[t3-t4,f]` are both 0, and the only function with indefinite integral 0 everywhere is constant 0 as far as I know. Not necessarily the most helpful for other expression though, since `Integrate` is really slow otherwise. `DiracDelta` is arguably not defined outside of an integral though, so perhaps the lack of simplification is intentional.

Comment: @eyorble: Up to traditional math (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function as a first reading and W. Rudin, Functional analysis as a second reading), Integrate[t1-t2,f] has no sense. Therefore, "the only function with indefinite integral 0 everywhere is constant 0 " is not applicable here.

Comment: `Integrate[(t1 - t2) g[f], {f, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]` evaluates to `0` which might be interpreted as `t1==t2` in the sense of distributions.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: Can you kindly explain what is g[f] and give a reference to your statement? TIA.

Comment: `g[f]` acts as a generic and symbolic test function. "Distribution" is meant in [this  sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)).

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: Unfortunately, Integrate[(t1 - t2) g[f], {f, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}] produces zero for an arbitrary g[f].

Comment: @user64494 What's unfortunate about that? That just means that `t1` equals `t2` in the sense of distributions. That was exactly my point you know...

Comment: Admittedly, there is some room for interpretation. Mathematica must assume that `g` is at least continuous so that integration agrainst a Dirac-distribution makes sense.

Comment: If ou put `f0` to be equal a real number, say 5, then `t1 - t2 // FullSimplify` gives zero. So, maybe try to identify what is `f0`, real, integer, complex, or restrict its range.